# Cordova + Visual Studio 2015 edge.node error

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, cordova

When I want to build my cordova app in vs2015 then I get the following error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The edge module has not been pre-compiled for node.js version
>   v6.9.1. You must build a custom version of edge.node. Please refer to
>   https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge for building
>   instructions. Katalog C:\Users\m.hüttl\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Katalog - Kopie\Katalog\MDAVSCLI 1

This is what I already tried:

- List item
- update node.js
- update all global packages
- downgrade edge.js to version 4.0

Currently installed versions:

- Node: 6.9.1
- Cordova: 6.1.1
- Edge: 5.0.0
- Edge-cs: 0.2.7

Answer (score 1):

try going to the folder C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac and changing the package.json to use edge version 4.0.0, deleting the edge folder in the node_modules, and running npm install in the vs-tac folder

You can also verify if the  Joyent Node.js is properly installed. Try running VS setup checking the Joyent Node.js installation
[image]

Comment: I already tried to install version 4.0.0 of edge but it didn't work. Joyent node.js is installed

Comment: did you delete the edge folder in the node_modules?

Comment: take a look at this discussion https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/issues/363

Comment: i don't know why but i reinstalled vs2015 and it worked